# Getting error "must declare the scalar variable" in SQL function even though it is declared

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, functions, table-valued-parameters, user-defined-table-type

I am altering `function` like:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CalculateListing](@Listing TypeListingDatePrice READONLY)
RETURNS TypePreviousListingResult 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tbl_ListingDateDetails TypePreviousListingResult   
    RETURN @tbl_ListingDateDetails
END
GO
```

But throwing error as:

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_CalculateListing, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@tbl_ListingDateDetails".
```

Why this giving error and asking for declaration even though I have declared that before using that variable?

TypePreviousListingResult is a table type created as `CREATE TYPE TypePreviousListingResult AS TABLE...`.

Previous question: [How to write function in sql which accept table as input and return result back as table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/127076/1192)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. For Multistatement TVFs, you just need `RETURN;` instead of `RETURN @variable;`.
2. It does not appear as though you can use a User-Defined Table Type (UDTT) as the return table type. That will need to be specified explicitly (i.e. each column name and datatype).

If this were a Scalar UDF, then the syntax of specifying only the datatype name in the `RETURNS` clause, and specifying the variable name in the `RETURN` statement, would be correct. However, you cannot return `TABLE` (or `CURSOR`) types from a Scalar UDF.

Please see the MSDN page for [CREATE FUNCTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) for more details.

You will need something along the lines of:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CalculateListing]
(
  @Listing dbo.TypeListingDatePrice READONLY
)
RETURNS @ListingDateDetails TABLE (ColumnName DataType,...)
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Do stuffs

    RETURN;
END;
GO
```

---

For a broader discussion of the available techniques to pass sets of rows around, see: [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://sommarskog.se/share_data.html) by [Erland Sommarskog](http://sommarskog.se/index.html).