# How can I pass column to function in sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate

I'm calculating median as:

```sql
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE
(
    ID INT
)

Select 
(
        (
            Select Top 1 ID
            From   
            (
                Select  Top 50 Percent ID
                From    @Temp
                Where   ID Is NOT NULL
                Order By ID
            ) As A
            Order By ID DESC
        ) + 
        (
            Select Top 1 ID
            From   
            (
                Select  Top 50 Percent ID
                From    @Temp
                Where   ID Is NOT NULL
                Order By ID DESC
            ) As A
            Order By ID Asc
        )
) / 2
```

Above query I want to use. But, in my case there are so many `columns` for those I want to calculate `MEDIAN`. But I think it would be bad to repeat above block of code for each `column`.
So, I'm trying to define separate function which would accept `column` values, process and return median.
Should I have to define `table-value-funtion` for that or there is another `optimized` way to do so??

---

This question is related to the following questions:

- [How to write function in sql which accept table as input and return result back as table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127076/how-to-write-function-in-sql-which-accept-table-as-input-and-return-result-back)
- [Getting error "must declare the scalar variable" in SQL function even though it is declared](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127185/getting-error-must-declare-the-scalar-variable-in-sql-function-even-though-it)
- [why unable to execute table-valued function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127307/why-unable-to-execute-table-valued-function)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127328/how-to-use-udf-function-in-insert-into-select-from-clause
- [Calculating multiple medians](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127473/how-to-insert-update-table-by-calling-function-in-it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are much more efficient ways to calculate a simple or grouped median than the one shown in your question:

[What is the fastest way to calculate the median?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median)
[Best approaches for grouped median](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/t-sql-queries/grouped-median)

The general winner for 2012 is a method by Peter Larsson. The pattern is:

#### Simple Median

```
SELECT
    Median = AVG(1.0 * SQ.YourColumn)
FROM 
(
    SELECT NumRows = COUNT_BIG(*) 
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE ColumnName IS NOT NULL
) AS C
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT YT.ColumnName
    FROM dbo.YourTable AS YT
    WHERE YT.ColumnName IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY YT.ColumnName ASC
    OFFSET (C.NumRows - 1) / 2 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - C.NumRows % 2) ROWS ONLY
) AS SQ;
```

#### Grouped Median

```
SELECT
    SQ2.GroupingColumn,
    SQ2.Median
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        GroupingColumn,
        NumRows = COUNT_BIG(*) 
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE ColumnName IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        GroupingColumn
) AS C
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT 
        Median = AVG(1.0 * SQ1.YourColumn)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT YT.ColumnName
        FROM dbo.YourTable AS YT
        WHERE 
            YT.GroupingColumn = C.GroupingColumn
            AND YT.ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY 
            YT.ColumnName ASC
            OFFSET (C.NumRows - 1) / 2 ROWS
            FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - C.NumRows % 2) ROWS ONLY
    ) AS SQ1
) AS SQ2;
```

To maximize the performance of the `OFFSET` method above, you may need to [add a locking hint](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/07/sql-plan/locking-and-performance) (advanced topic). Suitable indexing will also be required, of course.

#### Code reuse

This is hard to achieve directly with a T-SQL function, since these do not allow the execution of dynamic SQL (assuming you were thinking of passing in the column name).

There are several ways around this, including using a function to generate the dynamic SQL text itself, which can then be executed by the caller. There aren't really enough details in the question to say which approach would be most suitable for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to calculate a Median value, there are a few ways to do this depending on what version of SQL Server you (or someone else, perhaps) are on. Dwain Camps wrote two articles for Simple Talk in which he collected several pure T-SQL options from various folks, gives examples of each and compares their performance:

- [Calculating the Median Value within a Partitioned Set Using T-SQL](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/calculating-the-median-value-within-a-partitioned-set-using-t-sql/)
- [The Performance of the T-SQL Window Functions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-performance-of-the-t-sql-window-functions/)

However, I don't think you can encapsulate any of those methods into a function for easy re-use. For that you would need to use SQLCLR in order to create a [User-Defined Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregates) (UDA). I wrote an article several years ago showing how to create a UDA, using Median as the example :-)

[Getting The Most Out of SQL Server 2005 UDTs and UDAs](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/getting-the-most-out-of-sql-server-2005-udts-and-udas)

Regarding that article, please keep in mind:

- The article was written in 2007, before SQL Server 2008 came out, which introduced an improvement (i.e. allowing for storing more than 8000 bytes) that renders the compression technique shown in the article to be somewhat unnecessary. But, it should be fairly easy to remove the `GZipStream` stuff and change `MaxByteSize` from `8000` to `-1`.
- You don't *need* to code anything since the article includes, at the bottom, a SQL script that installs the UDA so you can just download, run, and use the Median aggregate :-)

See also:

- [CREATE AGGREGATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-aggregate-transact-sql)
- [SqlUserDefinedAggregateAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqluserdefinedaggregateattribute)
- [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=db_127310) (a SQLCLR library, which I am the author of, but there is a Free version that includes **Agg_Median**)

Comment: While generally a fan of SQLCLR, it's tough to recommend a UDA for this, given the lack of support for `IsInvariantToOrder`, and the consequent impact on memory use and performance compared with the best T-SQL methods. The basic implementation is *extremely* limited in maximum input size, meaning the query could fail unexpectedly. Extending it to LOB size as suggested, is not without significant implications either.

Comment: @PaulWhite Fair enough with regards to larger data sets. I could add a caveat regarding context and include your comment. But `MaxByteSize = -1` doesn't mean someone will be using >= 1 MB; it could just as easily be 9 - 10k. Though I have not tested the impact of setting to `-1` yet still only using < 8k.