# Calculating multiple medians

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate

I have defined `function` with `table value parameter` which `returns` `median` as per values passed to it. `Function` defined as:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetMedian](@List TypeMedian READONLY)
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
    <function body>
    END
```

And `Table Type` `TypeMedian` definition as:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TypeMedian] AS TABLE(
    [VALUE] [int] NULL
)
```

Now I have a `table` `Listing` with filled values in it as and a `table` `RESULT` to be filled according to `table` `Listing`:

`Tables structure` as

```
LISTING(ListingCol1,ListingCol2,ListingCol3,ListingCol4,ListingCol5)
RESULT(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5)
```

Listing table has more that 1000 rows of data.

All `column` from both `tables` are of type `int`.
Now I want to fill `columns` of `RESULT table` and that `column` could be calculate as:

```
Col1 = SUM(ListingCol1)
Col2 = SUM(ListingCol2)
Col3 = dbo.fn_GetMedian(ListingCol3)
Col4 = dbo.fn_GetMedian(ListingCol4)
Col5 = dbo.fn_GetMedain(ListingCol5)
```

And I'm doing so as:

```
INSERT INTO RESULT(Col1)
SELECT SUM(ListingCol1)

Update RESULT
SET Col2 = SUM(ListingCol2)

DECLARE @tbl_Median TypeMedian

INSERT INTO @tbl_Median
SELECT ListingCol3
FROM Listing

UPDATE RESULT
SET Col3 = dbo.fn_GetMedian(@tbl_Median)

-- For next column
DELETE FROM @tbl_Median

INSERT INTO @tbl_Median
SELECT ListingCol4
FROM Listing

UPDATE RESULT
SET Col4 = dbo.fn_GetMedian(@tbl_Median);
```

--And this update query I repeating for remaining columns.
How could I do that in single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two sums and three medians, on a single table, I honestly can't see the benefit of using a complicated dynamic or function-based solution.

It is quite easy to construct a single query using Peter Larsson's median method that [I showed you before](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127311/1192):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Listing
(
    ListingCol1 integer NULL,
    ListingCol2 integer NULL,
    ListingCol3 integer NULL,
    ListingCol4 integer NULL,
    ListingCol5 integer NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Result
(
    Col1 integer NULL,
    Col2 integer NULL,
    Col3 integer NULL,
    Col4 integer NULL,
    Col5 integer NULL
);

-- Just to show indexes are helpful for the median calculations
CREATE INDEX i ON dbo.Listing (ListingCol3)
CREATE INDEX j ON dbo.Listing (ListingCol4)
CREATE INDEX k ON dbo.Listing (ListingCol5)
```

#### Solution

```
INSERT dbo.Result
(
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3,
    Col4,
    Col5
)
SELECT
    SC.SumCol1,
    SC.SumCol2,
    SQ3.MedianCol3,
    SQ4.MedianCol4,
    SQ5.MedianCol5
FROM 
(
    -- Sums + counts needed for the median calculations
    SELECT 
        SumCol1 = SUM(L.ListingCol1),
        SumCol2 = SUM(L.ListingCol2),
        CountCol3 = COUNT_BIG(L.ListingCol3),
        CountCol4 = COUNT_BIG(L.ListingCol4),
        CountCol5 = COUNT_BIG(L.ListingCol5)
    FROM dbo.Listing AS L
) AS SC
CROSS APPLY 
(
    -- Median for column 3
    SELECT
        MedianCol3 = AVG(1.0 * SQ.ListingCol3)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            L3.ListingCol3
        FROM dbo.Listing AS L3
        WHERE 
            L3.ListingCol3 IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY 
            L3.ListingCol3 ASC
        OFFSET (SC.CountCol3 - 1) / 2 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - SC.CountCol3 % 2) ROWS ONLY
    ) AS SQ
) AS SQ3
CROSS APPLY 
(
    -- Median for column 4
    SELECT
        MedianCol4 = AVG(1.0 * SQ.ListingCol4)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            L4.ListingCol4
        FROM dbo.Listing AS L4
        WHERE 
            L4.ListingCol4 IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY 
            L4.ListingCol4 ASC
        OFFSET (SC.CountCol4 - 1) / 2 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - SC.CountCol4 % 2) ROWS ONLY
    ) AS SQ
) AS SQ4
CROSS APPLY 
(
    -- Median for column 5
    SELECT
        MedianCol5 = AVG(1.0 * SQ.ListingCol5)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            L5.ListingCol5
        FROM dbo.Listing AS L5
        WHERE 
            L5.ListingCol5 IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY 
            L5.ListingCol5 ASC
        OFFSET (SC.CountCol5 - 1) / 2 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - SC.CountCol5 % 2) ROWS ONLY
    ) AS SQ
) AS SQ5;
```

Expected execution plan shape:

[image: Plan]

Answer (score 2):

> And this update query I repeating for remaining columns. How could I do that in single query?

Performance implications aside for a moment, the easiest way to accomplish this in a single query<sup>**</sup> is by creating a User-Defined Aggregate (UDA) via SQLCLR. This is what I described in my answer to your related question:

[How can I pass column to function in sql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127303/how-can-i-pass-column-to-function-in-sql/127310#127310)

If you had such a function, you could do the following:

```sql
INSERT INTO RESULT(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
  SELECT SUM(ListingCol1) AS [Col1],
         SUM(ListingCol2) AS [Col2],
         dbo.AggMedian(ListingCol3) AS [Col3],
         dbo.AggMedian(ListingCol4) AS [Col4],
         dbo.AggMedian(ListingCol5) AS [Col5]
  FROM   LISTING;
```

With that said, performance is still something that needs to be considered. The approach shown above does not work in all situations. If the `LISTING` table has millions of rows (at least millions per each grouping), then this might not work. But if each grouping has 5000 rows, or maybe even 10,000 or something along those lines, and the process doesn't run multiple times per minute, then you should be fine. Of course, as with anything, it should be tested against your actual data to determine if there is a performance issue or not.

<sup>**</sup> By "easiest way in a single query", I am assuming that the desired method is one that can be easily applied in multiple situations, especially ad hoc queries.